# Looking for a TV/Movie about two kids being chased by a ghost in a field

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

When I was a kid in 2005-2008, I remember flipping through channels until I saw something scary. I don't remember if it was a TV show or movie, probably a movie.

Two kids are running through a field. Brother and sister. A scary ghostly lady is flying towards them. They run into their house. A old man (their uncle?) berates them for running into the house. The kids are panicking and begging him to lock the doors.

Myabe it took place in the 1800s or early 20th century? I remember old timey vibes.

The old man looks out the window and sees the woman. He decides to open the door. The kids are super scared.

Thats all I remember. My mother probably turned off the TV or changed the channel.

Any ideas?